# Embed a fragment ML in the Dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following function:

```
function inscrire(un, chaine) {
    conteneur = typeof un == 'string' ? bider(un) : un
    conteneur.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chaine))
}
```

Unfortunately, if `chaine` contains tags, for example:

```
ddddddddddddddd<li>kkkkk is not defined</li><li>fffffffffffffffffffff</li>
```

It appears in the output. How should you write the above function to handle this?

*(This is an English translation, for the original please see the edit history)*

Comment: Please ask your questions in english.

Comment: Unfortunately to few of us speak French to support you meaningfully here. Support the project of a French version: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/french-stack-overflow-francais - si tu ne connais pas stackoverflow, tu ne seras pas decu. Une version francaise est en project, suis le lien.

Answer (score 0):

`createTextNode` is to create text, so it's normal that it won't render your HTML tags. You could use the `innerHTML` property to insert your HTML code or design a new function in which the tags would be added with a `createElement`.